# Copy dynamically created file into built app package

Tags: ios, xcode

I have a file that I create in the `${SRCROOT}` folder of my iOS project when run. I want to copy this file so that when I build my app it is embedded in the package.

E.g.

- When the app is built I create a file `xyz.txt`
- I want this file to be copied to the app like a normal resource E.g. `MyApp.app/xyz.txt`

Here is what I have tried:

I have created a `Build Phase` -> `Run Script` with the following:

> cp "${SRCROOT}/xyz.txt ${DSTROOT}/xyz.txt

The above doesn't copy the file to where I want it to go. I have looked at [this](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/DeveloperTools/Reference/XcodeBuildSettingRef/1-Build_Setting_Reference/build_setting_ref.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40003931-CH3-SW88) list of build variables but I'm not sure which one will work for my purpose.

How can I copy the created `xyz.txt` file to the main app bundle as a build phase?

Comment: You can't do this through "Copy Bundle Resources" on the Build Phases tab of XCode?

Comment: Doesn't sound like it, because it's not a local resource until the build process is complete and the file is generated

Comment: @MarcusAdams Justin is correct, the file doesn't exist on disk until generated. The above question is a simplified example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the answer in this question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7287596/1144632

I ended up using the following in my `Run Script`

```
cp "${SRCROOT}/xyz.txt" "${BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR}/${UNLOCALIZED_RESOURCES_FOLDER_PATH}/xyz.txt"
```

Answer (score 0):

From Xcode 7.3, it seems that *${BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR}* points to another location and you cannot get file path using *NSBundle.pathForResource()*

At least when you try to copy plist or some file into Test bundle.

This is what works for me (in **Run Script**):

```
cp "${SRCROOT}/App/Resources/Custom.plist" "${TARGET_BUILD_DIR}/${UNLOCALIZED_RESOURCES_FOLDER_PATH}/MyPlist.plist"
```