# Shared library and localizable.strings

Tags: objective-c, macos, xcode4.2

I have created a shared library using Xcode 4.2 and objective c. My library includes a strings resource file that contains error messages. I then created a test application that loads and uses my library. I can't get to the string resource unless I manually copy the localizable.strings file into my test application project. Is there a way to access the resources contained in a library directly without copying to resource file?

Comment: Is the resource being added in copy resource phase in static library ?

Comment: The library is dynamic. No I did not use copy phase, I just copied manually to see if that worked. I'd like to not have to copy the resource if possible. Is there a way to export the resource and access directly from the library?

Comment: try to see this question of mine and see if it helps, I had a problem introducing a bundle in main project http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6690080/how-to-include-a-bundle-in-main-project-xcode-4

Comment: and this related one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8785346/can-a-datamodel-of-coredata-be-part-of-any-other-bundle-than-main-bundle/8786812#8786812 for including and accessing element included from other bundles into main bundle