# Can you add a build product from a different project as a bundle resource in XCode?

Tags: xcode, xcode4

I have two projects in an Xcode workspace.  I would like to add the build product of project B as a bundle resource in project A.   I have already configured the scheme of project A to build project B first.  Is there a proper way to do this besides simply adding the build product of project B from the file system?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was able to add the product of project B into project A in the following manner.  I simply dragged the product of project B from the Project Navigator into the Copy Bundle Resources pane of project A.  It can be tricky as you cannot initiate the drag by selecting the icon of the product -- I succeeded only by dragging its title.  It was not necessary to make project B a target dependency of target A; the build dependency can be managed instead by schemes (which was the way I originally had the workspace configured).

Answer (score 3):

The same question is somewhat answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7118177/470225. It isn't a perfect solution, but it is working for me. You can add a 'Run Script' build phase to copy the resources bundle into the app binary. Here is the script:

```
cp -R -f $BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR/MyBundle.bundle $BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR/$CONTENTS_FOLDER_PATH/
```

Answer (score 0):

You can go to your project A's build phases tab and add project B's product to the "Copy Bundle Resources" build phase. Make sure to add a dependency for project B.

Comment: Unforuntately project B's product does not show up as an option as a target dependency (it is not a target of project a, it simply shares a workspace) nor is it available to be added as a bundle resource.  Thanks though...  trying to figure out if a product of a different project can be added as a bundle resource.

Comment: If you drag project B in project A, you can select project B's targets as dependencies and resources.

Comment: That gets me a step closer, thanks.  That allows me to add project B as a target dependency.  Unfortunately, project B's product still doesn't show up as an option when I try to add a bundle resource to project A.

Comment: Taking a look at the project would help.. Here is a tutorial on sub-projects: http://www.cocoanetics.com/2011/12/sub-projects-in-xcode/

Comment: Another question with answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4219054/xcode-adding-a-project-as-a-build-dependency

Comment: You helped me get as far as this last answer does already  :)

Answer (score 0):

Should it be `cp -R -L -f $BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR/MyBundle.bundle $BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR/$CONTENTS_FOLDER_PATH/` with `-L`, without this, during Archive only symbolic link is copied to content folder path and app is crashing becasue don't see real resources.