# Using Core Data in a Framework

Tags: objective-c, core-data, frameworks

I'm trying to create a framework which uses Core Data. I have my data model included in the framework.

For some reason though, when I try to use the framework in a project, the framework's objects are unable to find either the momd or mom files in the framework.

I tried looking, but couldn't find a proper tutorial on how to correctly use Core Data with a framework.

Could anyone point me into the right direction?

Comment: See implementations for https://github.com/danielctull/DCTCoreDataStack and https://github.com/magicalpanda/MagicalRecord. Maybe you could find something useful.

Comment: I suppose that with 'framework' you mean instead 'static library' to reuse in your projects. If yes (but it may apply to framewrok as well), I had a similiar problem time ago. By default the xcdatamodel and other resources are not included in the bundle, see this question of mine: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6690080/how-to-include-a-bundle-in-main-project-xcode-4